# how to open a PDF with an ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script that downloads a PDF file from the server and prompts you to either open it, or save it. The script accepts a one time token, which is used in place of a file name, to hide the file name.

If you go to the actual php page, http://example.com/files/download/token the script works fine and it downloads the PDF.

I could just send people to that page with a standard link tag, but once the file downloads I need to update content on that page which is returned through that download script.

Is there any way to have ajax call open up a new window where the file will download and then return the data that I need to update the current page?

There is more to the download script, but the main piece is the actual downloading part:

```
 header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
 $this->load->helper('file');
 readfile("static/temp_statements/".$local_file_name);
 unlink("static/temp_statements/".$local_file_name);
```

Comment: You need to donwload a file and after that, you need more data that will be used to update the page?

Comment: Yea, so basically you click on the download link which contains a one time token to download file. Then once the file is downloaded I need to update that one time token link so they can click on it again.

Comment: So I want the ajax call to return the new token, so I can add that in, and also open up a new tab or window which will contain the actual download

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One trick that I have used in the past that might be useful to you is

- Supply a query param in your ajax call to download the PDF.  This will be a unique name.
- The server process that streams the PDF for download sets a cookie with this unique name.
- You poll in your page waiting for this cookie to appear.
- When the cookie appears you can assume the file has downloaded, and you can do your contingent action.

And you do not need to open a window to make this happen.  You could just append an invisible iframe like this:

```
$(some selector).append($("<iframe width='1' height='1' frameborder='0' src='" + url + "'></iframe>"));
```

In the interests of honesty and transparency, I originally found this idea from this SO answer and it worked for me: [Detect when browser receives file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download)